# Conversion rate optimization algorithm

Tags: php, ab-testing

I'm working with split A/B testing and I'm using this library:
https://github.com/namshi/AB

Each test generates a seed that tells AB tester which parameters to use.

Let's say that I want to get best conversion rate for checkout page, using different variables, like background color, checkout button color, texts etc.

What kind of algorithm would get the seed with best conversion rate?

What I tried:

- Every seed has "weight", more weight = most likely is picked
- On successful conversion seed is stored and more weight is added to current seed
- In every run, one random seed is added with 10% of total seeds weight, so 1 of 10 visitors gets random seed to keep testing new variations

Code I have written already:

```
public function conversionTest()
{

    // Store successful conversion to $seeds arr
    $seeds = [];

    // Run 200 "conversions"
    for ($i = 0; $i < 200; $i++) {

        // Initialize seed container
        $container = $this->initializeSeedArr($seeds);

        // Random seed test
        $randomSeed = new Test('random-seed', $container);

        // Get seed
        $seed = $randomSeed->getVariation();

        // Push to $seeds as "successful conversion"
        $seeds[] = $seed;

    }

    dd($container);

}

private function initializeSeedArr($container)
{
    $arr = [];

    $count = count($container);

    // Add random seed with 10% "weight" of container count
    $arr[$this->randomSeed()] = $this->getSeedWeight($count);

    // Add rest of the seeds
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($container); $i++) {
        // Get current seed
        $seed = $container[$i];

        // If multiple conversion add more weight to current seed
        $arr[$seed] = isset($arr[$seed]) ? $arr[$seed] + 1 : 1;
    }

    return $arr;
}

private function randomSeed()
{
    return mt_rand();
}

private function getSeedWeight($count)
{
    $round = (int)round($count * 0.1);
    $round = $round < 1 ? 1 : $round;
    return $round;
}
```

There is a problem with this approach, here is what most of the results looks like.

```
array:21 [▼
  1641197740 => 20
  1787918404 => 155
  2108274654 => 1
  667244174 => 7
  1296436374 => 3
  213433208 => 4
  450097167 => 4
  465517336 => 1
  1071877664 => 1
  1430346867 => 6
  444753032 => 2
  1802187446 => 3
  1937663980 => 2
  315179639 => 2
  2067012650 => 1
  717546160 => 1
  160677944 => 1
  822938190 => 2
  553738679 => 1
  20707768 => 1
  932884407 => 1
]
```

Seeds on top of the list gets most of the "conversions" and most of the weight, new seeds are added and tested but they don't get any weight as more conversions starts to pour on first seeds. So in long run this is not really good solution.

How would you do this?